# jQuery redirect is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to achieve redirection after values has been sent to my php script.
Value sent to the script correctly but redirect is not working in Firefox, in chrome it's also working fine.

This is piece of code where i put redirect.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            // Show a thank you message
            var theLanguage = $('html').attr("lang");
            if (theLanguage == "nl-NL") {
              url = "/Thanks/";
              $(location).attr("href", url);
            }
            else if (theLanguage == "fr-FR") {
              url = "/fr/merci/";
              $(location).attr("href", url);
            }
            else {
              url = "/en/thanks/";
              $(location).attr("href", url);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what is the better way to do that which is cross browser compatible?

Thanks

Comment: Any console messages in Firefox? Also only have one `location.href=url;` outside the ifs. What does `console.log($('html').attr("lang"));` tell you in Firefox compared to Chrome?

Comment: How about `location.href = url;` — there's absolutely no reason to (attempt to) do it with jQuery.

Comment: I also tried this.. Same issue

Comment: I'd also use `navigator.language` instead of trying to get a "lang" attribute from the `<html>` element.

Comment: @Zain What does `console.log($('html').attr("lang"))`  tell you in Firefox compared to Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just submit the form and redirect from the server?

If you cannot just do that, then

1. Use jQuery since you have it
2. preventDefault on the submit event to not submit the form

You likely need this instead of your xmlhttprequest. Note the preventDefault

```js
$(function() {
  $("#yourFormId").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'yourserverproces.php', // this.action will work if the form has an action
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        // Show a thank you message
        var theLanguage = $('html').attr("lang"),
          url = "/en/thanks/";
        if (theLanguage == "nl-NL") {
          url = "/Thanks/";
        } else if (theLanguage == "fr-FR") {
          url = "/fr/merci/";
        }
        location.href = url;
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The `location.href = "url"` should work but if that gives you too many issues you can also try and use `window.location.assign("url")`